# LibGDX parsing standard json to an object

Tags: java, json, libgdx

I have a very basic problem.
I read though the LibGDX documentation a few times regarding JSON and Google around for an answer but it still does't work..

Basically I'm pulling json from a server like such which works as:

```
{"id":1,"facebook_id":"23432232","json":"{\"json\":\"test\"}"}
```

I have a class like this:

```
public class ServerJson
{
public static final String NAME = "ServerJson";

private int id;
private String facebookID;
private String json;

public ServerJson(){}

public ServerJson(int id, String facebookID, String json)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.facebookID = facebookID;
    this.json = json;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getFacebookID() {
    return facebookID;
}

public String getJson() {
    return json;
}
```

When I try to parse the code, it doesn't work. I get null:

```
String resultString = httpResponse.getResultAsString(); //{"id":1,"facebook_id":"23432232","json":"{\"json\":\"test\"}"}
Json json = new Json();
ServerJson serverJson = json.fromJson(ServerJson.class, resultString);
log(serverJson.getFacebookID()); //<< Is null.
```

Comment: what does resultString look like

Comment: Updated, it's the same as the result up-top.

Comment: can you do serverJson.getId() is that working?

Comment: Thanks man, I've been trying to figure this out all day. Was something as simple as the fields were not matching up!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the fields of your object class match up with the fields of the json object.